# Jquery Cannot use 'in' operator to search for 'display' in undefined

Tags: jquery, html

This is my HTML

```
   <div class="V_CPp Elss <?php echo $Show; ?>">
                           <span class="ViewC">View more comments</span>
                          </div>
                          <div class="Elss <?php echo $Show2;?>">
                            <p>Show first</p>
                            <div class="Options SB_Pop" numb-i="1" data-c="2"><p class="CSSnOT">Soon</p></div>
                            <div class="Options SB_OF"  numb-i="2"><p class="CSSnOT">New ones first</p></div>
                            <div class="Options SB_NF"  numb-i="3"><p class="CSSnOT">Old ones first</p></div>
                            <div class="Options SB_CPop" numb-i="4"><p class="CSSnOT">Soon</p></div>
                          </div>
```

and I have got this jquery function

```
var changed=false;
    function Sb(el){
            var S_b_Clicked = el.children(".Options").first().attr("data-c");
             if (changed==false) {
             S_b_Clicked++;
             el.children(".Options").first().attr("data-c",S_b_Clicked);
             el.animate({width: "120px", height: "130px",fontSize:"40px"}, 500);
             el.children('p').animate({marginTop: "23px",marginLeft: "-9px",},500);
             if (S_b_Clicked%2==1) {
                el.children().show(800);
                }else{
                 el.children(".Options").hide(1000);   
                 el.animate({width: "80px", height: "90px",fontSize:"25px"}, 500);
                 el.children('p').animate({marginTop: "15px",marginLeft: "-16px",},500);
                }
            }
    }
```

I made this function so i can use it in various places in my code

And i want to call this function onclick some element like this

```
$(".S_b_SelectP").click(Sb($(this)));
```

But it returns me error in console

```
jquery.js:6474 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot use 'in' operator to search for 'display' in undefined
```

Comment: You need to show html.

Answer (score 0):

It's hard to reproduce your problem since your html still contains php statements of which we don't know the output, but probably the main problem is the way you're adding the click events. Your example should be

```
$(".S_b_SelectP").click(function(){Sb($(this))});
```

The `click` method expects a function, you're *applying* a function and therefore passing its result as argument.